# Simple(?) MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm  very new with MySQL and have been stuck on a query for a while. I thought I would have to use a subquery but doing that didn't work because it returns multiple rows. Here's what I've got so far:

```
    SELECT im.fb_id, im.interest_id, i.name
    FROM interest_map AS im
    LEFT JOIN interests AS i ON i.id = im.interest_id
    WHERE i.category = 'Pet supplies'
```

This gives me all of the users who have interests under the category 'Pet supplies'. What I want is to:

1. Start with user A
2. Collect all of user A's interests under category X
3. Find all other users who have matching interests

The interests don't need to match explicitly, meaning that User A can have interests 1, 2, 4 and User B can have interests 2, 3, 5 and they would still match on interest 2.

My tables look like this:

```
    users: id, firstname, last_name
    interests: id, name, category
    interest_map: user_id, interest_id
```

Also if anyone knows what this kind of query is called so I can read up about other queries  like it I would really appreciate that!

Comment: Note that your WHERE clause effectively renders your OUTER JOIN as an INNER JOIN. Oh, and it's called a simple JOIN

Comment: I had it as an INNER join earlier but tried LEFT just to see if my result set changed (note I've been working with SQL for maybe a week or two).

I really just need to map all of User A's interests to matching interests that every other person in the table has but I don't know what type of JOIN to do that with.

Answer (score 1):

You do this by moving the condition on the *second* table into the `on` clause:

```
SELECT im.fb_id, im.interest_id, i.name
FROM interest_map im LEFT JOIN
     interests i
     ON i.id = im.interest_id AND
        i.category = 'Pet supplies';
```

When the `LEFT JOIN` doesn't match a record, it produces a `NULL` value.  So, when you say `i.cateogry = 'Pet Supplies'`, the value of `i.category` is `NULL` and the comparison fails.

Putting the condition in the `on` clause fixes this.  However, it is going to keep all the rows in the initial table.

I think you really want:

```
SELECT u.id, im.interest_id, i.name
FROM users u left outer join
     interest_map im
     on u.id = im.user_id LEFT JOIN
     interests i
     ON i.id = im.interest_id AND
        i.category = 'Pet supplies';
```

This will produce one row per user, with the appropriate interest.

Comment: (not sure that answers the question!?!?)

Comment: Is there a way to drop rows with null columns? This is much closer to what I'm trying to achieve. Both of your proposed queries returns results with null columns.

Comment: Switching to inner joins drops the null columns (I get the inner vs left join now, hooray!). The last piece is to filter out any of the interest columns that don't match. Like I stated in the question, User A likes things 1, 2, and 4 while User B likes things 2, 3, and 5. The result from the query should only show two rows: `User A | 2` and `User B | 2`

Answer (score -1):

Well, you should read all the user's A interests in an array. Then you can do a

```
SELECT * FROM interest_map WHERE interest_id in (array of user A interests)
```

IF you do this you can also see who matches use A the most, meaning you can do a.

```
SELECT count(*) as nr, user_id FROM interest_map WHERE interest_id in (array of user A interests) GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY nr DESC.
```

This will give you in descending order the users that match user A the most.

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

Comment: Because this is what JOINs are for!

Comment: Depends, if he already has the interests and in real life he should already have them then this `SELECT * FROM interest_map WHERE interest_id in (array of user A interests)` is faster then a join. I agree, the subquery is not necessary.

Comment: The SELECT with the subquery you propose at the end of your solution doesn't fit, it gives me all of the interests of the user rather than just the interests that match. Ideally I would want a table that looks like:


`user|interest name/id` that shows all users who also like the same things from the category that User A selects.

Comment: @Strawberry I see you deleted your last comment. For me this `SELECT * FROM tblProductCategoryRelation_PCAR WHERE idPCAT_PCAR IN (8, 151, 231)` runs in  0.004 s and this `SELECT second.* FROM tblProductCategoryRelation_PCAR first JOIN tblProductCategoryRelation_PCAR second ON first.idPCAT_PCAR = second.idPCAT_PCAR WHERE first.idPRD_PCAR = 945` runs in 0.011 s. I know, i know, naming conventions... old db.

Comment: Mihai, post up the sqlfiddle. I removed my comment because you said that a subquery was not necessary - meaning that you were now only 50% wrong!

Comment: I cannot upload a big enough sample to make a dent but this is the db structure http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/515e8/2. From my tests this SELECT * FROM tblProductCategoryRelation_PCAR WHERE idPCAT_PCAR IN (8, 151, 231) is faster than this SELECT second.* FROM tblProductCategoryRelation_PCAR first JOIN tblProductCategoryRelation_PCAR second ON first.idPCAT_PCAR = second.idPCAT_PCAR WHERE first.idPRD_PCAR = 945